# How to get file attributes/Status of one drive files in powershell

Tags: powershell, sharepoint, onedrive

We have excel files used as a Database by different users on microsoft teams. My OneDrive mapped to these files is : C:\OneDrive\my site\Database
Inside this folder I have a file called  :
Database.xlsx

we may add another file Database2.xlsx, but for the moment I need a help about the Database.xlsx

we use some vba to inject data inside Database.xlsx.
I would like to know if the file is opened or used or beeing syncrhonised by someone else to avoid  making changes to the file on the same time as another user.

I tried some code like :

```
Get-ChildItem "C:\OneDrive\my site\Database\" -file -recurse | Select-Object Attributes
```

and

```
$OneDriveDocs = "C:\OneDrive\my site\Database\"
$Shell = (New-Object -ComObject Shell.Application).NameSpace((Split-Path $OneDriveDocs))
$Status = $Shell.getDetailsOf($Shell.ParseName((Split-Path $OneDriveDocs -Leaf)),303)
Write-Output $Status
```

The problem with above codes is that they are giving me as it seems the status of the file C:\OneDrive\my site\Database\Database.xlsx like if it was a local file not like if it was a shared file on Microsoft Teams, because when someone is making changes to the file from his PC I am not able to detect that he is working on it.
Is there a way to check the file status or attributes on it's real sharepoint location (https://oursharepoints.com/Database and not on my mapped : "C:\OneDrive\my site\Database" to detect if someone else is making changes or syncrhonizing the file ?